# How to determine if a port is physically(hardware) bad

Tags: switch, hardware

We are using a 48 port 3com baseline switch and recently ports have started dropping, completely shutting off(no connection light) and have switched to another open port and moved on our merry way. 
   So now we are getting more and more ports dropping. I have run the diagnostics and the ports that have failed either have unknown or short test results. The ones that tested short was without a cable and with a cable. Is this a sign that the switch is failing, is there something I'm not doing right in my test. BTW I am not a network engineer just a hobbyist that understands enough that I've become IT manager at a small business.

Comment: Do you have access to the cli of the 3com baseline switch?

Comment: No i don't have the correct cable, but if I did what commands could be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LED display has one LED for each port, laid out in the same order as the ports are located on the front panel.
The LED's show speed and activity on the ports.

When the port LED is off, there is no link, when it is green, there is a 10/100Mbps link present and when it is amber, there is a 1000MB link present The port LED will flash when there is traffic being transmitted or received by the port.
Note: The LED's will not show whether the port is in full or half duplex mode.
The power and diagnostic LED's are used to indicate whether the switch is operating correctly.
Both Power and Diag LED's should be green when everything is okay.
If the power LED is off, or RED, then there is a power supply fault and the switch will not boot up.

The Diagnostic LED indicates the status of the switch.
When the switch is powered up, the Diag LED flashes green for about 40 seconds, then extinguishes. When the LED comes back to a solid green colour (approx 60 seconds) then the switch is ready to be managed or pass traffic.
The Diag LED will show if a loopback fault has occurred on a port, or if an internal cooling fan has failed.
It will flash red if a fan has failed, and the switch will continue to operate.
It will be solid red, and the corresponding port LED will flash amber/ green, if a port fails the loopback test at bootup. The switch will continue to operate, but the failed port will be disabled.